# Kids word for "lights shoes" (shoes that light up)

Tags: word-request

What do kids in America call these "lights shoes"? Do they just call them "lights shoes" or is there any name kids would call them?

[image: Light up shoes example]

Comment: I tried but found no kids' term for that. But the thing to be noted is it should be referred to as *lights shoes* *as you did but I found 'light shoes' manywhere) because *light shoes* is an all different category of shoes that weight very light and generally used for jogging.

Comment: I've seen many websites use the term "light up shoes".

Answer (score 3):

***Light-up*** shoes would be the preferred name for them.

***Light*** shoes, though a valid phrasing, would normally be taken with *light* as an adjective, so it's a description of their weight,

***?Lights*** shoes is a) an awkward phrase due to the "ts-sh" combination in the middle, and b) violates the normal rule that an attributive noun (**light**) should be singular.

Comment: I've only ever heard them referred to as "light-up shoes" (or "those awesome shoes that light up").

Comment: The technical name for them is probably something like "Pressure-sensitive illuminated-sole children's footwear."  :-)

Comment: There are also trademarked names for them. I happen to work for SKECHERS, one of the pioneers in this genre. They have the designations "Twinkle Toes(r)" which have tiny, glittering , often-muticolored lights, and "S Lites(r)" which have brighter, larger lights. You can see dozens of these styles at http://www.skechers.com/girls/styles/s-lights